# Child-process for cpu intensive task?

Tags: node.js

So I'm starting to use node.js for a project I'm doing.

When a client makes a request, My node.js server fetches from another server a json and then reformats it into a new json that gets served to this client. However, the json that the node server got from the other server can potentially be pretty big and so that "massaging" of data is pretty cpu intensive.

I've been reading for the past few hours how node.js isn't great for cpu tasks and the main response that I've seen is to spawn a child-process (basically a .js file running through a different instance of node) that deals with any cpu intensive tasks that might block the main event loop.

So let's say I have 20,000 concurrent users, that would mean it would spawn 20,000 os-level jobs as it's running these child-processes.

Does this sound like a good idea? (A different web server would just create 20,000 threads on the same process.)

I'm not sure if I should be running a child-process. But I do need to make a non-blocking cpu intensive task. Any ideas of what I should do?

Answer (score -2):

The people who say that don't know how to architect solutions.

NodeJS is exactly what it says, It is a node, and should be treated like such.

In your example, your node instance connects to an external api and grabs json to process and send back.

i.e.
1. Get // server.com/getJSON
2. Process the json
3. Post // server.com/postJSON

So what do you do? 
Ask yourself is time an issue? if so then node isnt the solution
However if you are more interested in raw processing power so instead of 1 request done in 4 seconds

You are interested in 200 requests finishing in 10 seconds, but each individual one taking about the full 10 seconds.

Diagnose how long your JSON should take to massage, if it is less than 1 second.
Just run 4 node instances instead of 1.

However if its more complex than that, Break the json into segments to process. And use asynchronous callbacks to process each segment

process.nextTick(function( doprocess(segment1); process.nextTick(function() {doprocess(segment2)

each doProcess calls the next doProcess

Node js will trade time between requests.

Now Take that solution and scale it too 4 node instances per server, and 2-5 servers

and suddenly you have an extremely scaleable and cost effective solution.

Comment: segmentize a json file, create 4 node instances per server, and 2-5 servers? and now I have an extremely scaleable and cost effective solution? .. gee whiz.

Comment: Its simpler than it seems. That 2-5 servers is for A huge amount of throughput. Thats years down the line from where you are. NodeJS was built to be used like a Node in a System, it is the bare minimum needed to do anything you want. It is not a prehashed solution to scaleability, however you can architect an extremely good system using it.